# Network Manager stuck at stage 5 of 5?

Tags: linux, networkmanager

After successfully installed Fedora 20, I did a scan in the log file to spot for errors. I am able to connect to the internet, but the network manager is repeatedly producing this two lines every few seconds. I don't believe this is the correct behaviour:

> NetworkManager[715]:  Activation (wlp0s26u1u3) Stage 5 of 5
>   (IPv6 Commit) scheduled...
>  NetworkManager[715]:  Activation
>   (wlp0s26u1u3) Stage 5 of 5 (IPv6 Commit) started..

Further up the log, I spotted some errors:

> NetworkManager[715]:  Couldn't acquire object manager proxy:
>   Error calling StartServiceByName for org.bluez:
>   GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.systemd1.LoadFailed: Unit
>   dbus-org.bluez.service failed to load: No such file or directory.
>   NetworkManager[715]:  (wlp0s26u1u3): add_pending_action (2):
>   'autoactivate' already added
>  NetworkManager[715]: file
>   devices/nm-device.c: line 6868 (nm_device_add_pending_action): should
>   not be reached
>  NetworkManager[715]:  (wlp0s26u1u3):
>   remove_pending_action (1): 'autoactivate' never added Jan 01 22:21:02
>   s1.fussfreecom NetworkManager[715]: file devices/nm-device.c: line
>   6919 (nm_device_remove_pending_action): should not be reached

It seems to be saying that it is stuck at stage 5 and needs some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug as described in the link below, we are all waiting for a fix.
https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1045860

Comment: Thanks. I see it is indeed the case. Even using live media on wireless got problem. Do you have any idea about the errors above? It seems unrelated to the stage 5 problem.